# Jmeter results tree is not red

Tags: jmeter

I am running Jmeter version 4.0. in GUI mode.
Even though the results of my HTTP response is not success i.e (Response headers: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found) the view tree result is not red?  I have searched the manuals for listeners but cant see why. Thank  you for your help

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example of this? You could use google.com as a domain for your http endpoint and post the XML configuration of your tests here in order for us to better understand what is happening. Your description is too open and people will likely not be able to help you effectively.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

[image: JMeter 4.0 HTTP 404]

The only thing I can think of is that you have [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) somewhere in your Test Plan configured to `Ignore Status`.

So:

1. Try executing your test plan on vanilla JMeter 4.0 (no plugins, no extra libraries)
2. Disable all assertions
3. Check *jmeter.log* file for any suspicious entries

If nothing helps - share your Test Plan somehow so we could take a look.

Comment: Thank you I just posted an image. IN my case I have  Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: Looking into your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp0SJ.png) - actual HTTP Status code is 200 (green rectangle), your `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` comes as [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), JMeter doesn't automatically check it. If you want to validate the header - you need to use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)  configured to header value. See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) for more details.